# Categorizing attributes by keyword in new field with field calculator in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, field-calculator, attribute-table, grouping

So, the [geological classification shapefile](http://philgis.org/general-country-datasets/geology-philippines) of the Philippines has the `'DESCRIPT'` field which contains the geological time scale of each feature.

- "Oligocene-miocene" and "Oligocene-miocene (igneous Rocks)" and "Oligocene-miocene (sedimentary & Metamorphic Rocks)"
- "Paleocene(?)-eocene (igneous Rocks)" and "Paleocene-eocene (sedimentary & Metamorphic Rocks)"
- "Undifferentiated" and "Undifferentiated (igneous Rocks)"

However, some attributes have varying but same time scale.

How could the "same" time scales categorized by creating another field which contains the category?

Categorizing the features by spotting if a keyword is in the feature or specifying the exact name of the feature.

Answer (score 2):

**CONTAINS** KEYWORD

You can make a field that writes the `"category"` of `'DESCRIPT'` features if it has a certain keyword using this code in the field calculator in the attribute table.

```sql
CASE
    WHEN "DESCRIPT" ILIKE '%Undifferentiated%' THEN 'dog'
    ELSE 'cat'
END
```

[image: example1]

**EQUALS EXACT** KEYWORD

If you want to categorize by exact word, the use this code:

```sql
CASE
    WHEN "DESCRIPT" = 'UNDIFFERENTIATED' THEN 'dog'
    WHEN "DESCRIPT" = 'UNDIFFERENTIATED (IGNEOUS ROCKS)' THEN 'fish'
    ELSE 'cat'
END
```

[image: example2]