# Symbolize an attribute field by keyword in that field in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, symbology

[This post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/355069/categorizing-attributes-by-keyword-in-new-field-with-field-calculator-in-qgis-3) is similar to what my issue is but I cannot generate a new field for my application. I'm working with US geology data where the age is stored as Eon - Era - Period - Epoch - Age in one field. However I need to apply symbology based on Epoch only. My idea is to apply symbology by some sort of keyword search within the data to apply symbology but I don't know how to do that or if its even possible. Another thought I had was to create a custom color ramp with the colors I plan to use and setting custom breaks but I'm not sure how to do that for strings and I only have a small subset of the entire national dataset since my computer can't handle the whole dataset at once.

For example lets say I have 2 attributes and one is Phanerozoic - Cenozoic - Tertiary-Neogene - Early Miocene - Burdigalian and the other attribute is Phanerozoic - Cenozoic - Tertiary-Neogene - Pliocene. And I need to apply a color to based on Pliocene and Miocene. I could make a symbology that lists out the whole attribute start to finish and apply the same color for things with the same Epoch but there are over 200 different ages I would then need to work through which is something I'd like to avoid doing if I can.

Additionally some of the data only go as far as era or period so wouldn't have an Epoch but would still need some sort of symbology. However I think this would be solved if I could find a way to symbolize by a "keyword" within each attribute

The reason I need to do it without generating a new column is because I am working on creating a template symbology that will be applied to many shapefiles for geology.

Comment: without generating a new column you wont get a method that work for both arcmap and qgis. Asking for both software made it two question and it could be closed as such, choose only one software or ask two separate question

Comment: Thanks for your help! The QGIS solution worked. I'll edit this post to be QGIS only and make a new post for ArcMap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These answer will work only for QGIS

If your field is consistantly as this : "Eon - Era - Period - Epoch - Age" the best way would be to use an expression to extract the part you need. This could be done with an expression like:

```
array_get ( string_to_array ( "YourFieldName" , 'separator' ) , index )
```

For your case remplace `'separator'` by `' - '` and set the index to what you want to extract (the index start at 0 so 0 will give you the Eon, 1 the Era, 2 the period,...)

Another way to do it is to use the rule based renderer and define as many rule as you need using the LIKE operator and % as wildcard character so something like :

```
"YourFieldName" LIKE '%Miocene%'
```

Will give you a categories of all record where the field "YourFieldName" include the string Miocene