# Symbolize an attribute by keyword in that field in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology

[This post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/355069/categorizing-attributes-by-keyword-in-new-field-with-field-calculator-in-qgis-3) is similar to what my issue is but I cannot generate a new field for my application. I'm working with US geology data where the age is stored as Eon - Era - Period - Epoch - Age in one field. However I need to apply symbology based on Epoch only. My idea is to apply symbology by some sort of keyword search within the data to apply symbology but I don't know how to do that or if its even possible in ArcMap

For example lets say I have 2 attributes and one is Phanerozoic - Cenozoic - Tertiary-Neogene - Early Miocene - Burdigalian and the other attribute is Phanerozoic - Cenozoic - Tertiary-Neogene - Pliocene. And I need to apply a color to based on Pliocene and Miocene. I could make a symbology that lists out the whole attribute start to finish and apply the same color for things with the same Epoch but there are over 200 different ages I would then need to work through which is something I'd like to avoid doing if I can.

Additionally some of the data only go as far as era or period so wouldn't have an Epoch but would still need some sort of symbology. However I think this would be solved if I could find a way to symbolize by a "keyword" within each attribute. In QGIS this is ruled based rendering which I haven't found in ArcMap.

The reason I need to do it without generating a new column is because I am working on creating a template symbology that will be applied to many shapefiles for geology so whatever I do has to be able to be applied as a style from the .lyr.

Comment: Are you able to use ArcGIS Pro instead of ArcMap? If so, would this meet your needs? https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/layer-properties/attribute-driven-symbology.htm

Comment: I originally thought it may have to be arcmap because arcpro doesn't output .lyr files but it looks like there may be a workaround to get .lyrx to .lyr. I'll look into this!

Comment: This doesn't seem like it'll achieve what I need. Unless someone is very good at arcade and knows something I'm missing. It seems that I'd need to write some sort of arcade expression that takes a search object and assigns colors based on keyword which is what I need but I'm not sure how to get there with my limited grasp of arcade.